# Is there a Python equivalent for the Perl module Term::VT102?

Tags: python, perl, screen-scraping, command-line-interface, vt100

In Perl there is a very handy module, Term::VT102, which allows you to create a screen in memory. This is very handy for scraping purposes since you can keep track of all the changes to portions of the screen and then export the screen as plain-text for processing. Is there an equivalent module in Python?

Followup Question: There are modules like Pexpect that allow you to screen scrape a VT100 screen, but how does VT100 differ from VT102?

Comment: This is a good question. I am looking forward to the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect), which has support for VT100, might be of help to you.

Comment: That's something completely different than what he asked for. Term:VT102 emulates a terminal, Pexpect helps you interface programs that make use of a terminal.

Comment: +1 @Leon, Dingo has a point, Pexpect includes an experimental component called "screen" that is meant to emulate a terminal screen (http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect#experimental_extensions). I am going to check it out and see if it does the same as the VT102 Perl module.

Comment: @Dingo - Do you know what the difference is between VT100 & VT102? Pexpect only mentions VT100.

Answer (score 3):

See also [ashttp](https://github.com/JulienPalard/ashttp) built on top of Pexcept:

> ```
> ashttp can serve any text application over http, like :
>
> $ ashttp 8080 top
> to serve a top on port 8080, or :
>
> $ ashttp 8080 watch -n 1 ls -lah /tmp
> to serve an actualized directory listing of /tmp
> ```

(Source: https://mdk.fr/blog/ashttp-vt100-screen-scraping-exported-over-http.html )